# I found a php code in my server , how can know what is mean?

Tags: php

How are you ?

I found a php code , but i can't know what is mean .. maybe some one put it in my server ..

it is strange ..

maybe you can know what is mean?

here : http://codepaste.net/3rj6y8

Comment: No, we don't explain code here. Please see [so-hints](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) and [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) or the FAQ on what Stackoverflow is for. -- Decoding obfuscated code has been covered as well. Use the search function.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a typical vulnerability exploit - your server has been hacked. On first examination of the obfuscated code, I see signs of a remote shell functionality that allows an attacker to take control over your server.

Reinstall the machine and make sure to close the vulnerability (for example, by examining your own and updating other software). For more details, refer to [this excellent serverfault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/218011/64731).

Answer (score 2):

It's some obfuscated code, probably server exploit.

Read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512425/how-to-deobfuscate-this-php-code-instructions-please-dont-just-do-it-for-me

According to [this page](http://translate.google.pl/translate?hl=pl&sl=pl&tl=en&u=http://aiv-dev.info/2011/04/14/ataki-na-web-aplikacje-cz-4/) is some webshell giving remote access to your server.

**Delete or move this file!**